# Problems using mapped network drive as Git Remote repository

Tags: git, version-control

I'm relatively new to git.  I am trying to create a remote repository on a mapped network drive (Z).   I have an existing project and repo on my C drive.  **I don't get any errors when I add the remote and push to it, but I can't see any project files have been copied to the Z drive, only the .git directory.**

This is what I have tried.

```
$ cd Z:       //mapped network drive
$ mkdir GitTest  
$ cd GitTest  
$ mkdir .git  
$ cd .git  
$ git --bare init  
$ cd c:  
$ cd GitTest   //location of existing local repository - a Visual Studio Project
$ git remote add origin z:/GitTest/.git  
$ git push -u origin --all
```

Here is results of my git push:

```
Counting objects: 466, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (421/421), done.
Writing objects: 100% (466/466), 25.63 MiB | 1.24 MiB/s, done.
Total 466 (delta 67), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (67/67), done.
To Z:/GitTest/.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your remote repo `z:/GitTest/.git` is a **bare repo—no working directory**, so you can’t find files directly. But actually they are exist. You can clone the remote repo, and then find the updated files in working directory by `git clone z:/GitTest/.git`.

Comment: Thank you , that makes sense.  I was now recreating these steps for another local repo, but now am getting error:  

   _fatal: 'Z:/GitTest/.git' does not appear to be a git repository
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository._

Comment: Ah yes I think that was the problem, I didn't create the .git folder before _git --bare init_  .    I was also able to clone the remote afterwards and get all the files.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Yeah, bare repo has no `.git` folder ;p